# Prove that two random variables are independent

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, random-variable, independence

I am struggling with the following problem (casella & berger 4.30(b)):

$$ \text{Suppose that} \;\;\;Y|X=x \sim normal(x,x^2) \;\; \text{and} \;\; X\sim uniform\,(0,1).\\\text{Prove that} \;\;\frac{Y}{X} \;\text{and}\; X \;\text{are independent.} $$

My attempt:

$$ \text{Let} \; u= y/x \;\; \text{and}\;\;v=x. \\
\text{Then} \;\;x= v,\;y = uv, \;and\;\;J = det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1  \\ v & u  \\\end{bmatrix}\right)=-v
\\ \text{Also, this transformation is 1-1 and }\\\text{maps the set} \;\mathscr X=\{(x,y): 0<x<1, \;-\infty<y<\infty \} \;\\\text{onto the set} \;\mathscr Y=\{(u,v): -\infty<u<\infty, \;0<v<1 \}.\\ \text{Therefore,} \;\;f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(v,uv) *|J| = f_{Y|X}(uv|v)f_{X}(v)*|v| =\frac{v}{\sqrt{2\pi}v^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2v^2}(uv-v)^2}I_{\mathscr Y}((u,v))\\\text{and thus,} \;f_{U,V}(u,v) =\frac{v}{\sqrt{2\pi}v^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2v^2}v^2(1-u)^2}I_{\mathscr Y}((u,v)) \;\text{can not be decomposed product of function of u and function of v.}\\\text{Hence},\;\frac{Y}{X}\;\text{and}\; X \;\text{are not independent.}
$$

However,
$$ \;\;\frac{Y}{X}\,|\,X=x \sim normal(1,1).\\\text{So}\;\; \frac{Y}{X}\,|\,X=x \;\;\text{does not depend on}\;x.
\\\text{Thus,} \;\;\frac{Y}{X} \;\text{and}\; X \;\text{are independent.}
$$

I don't know why my attempt is wrong.

Comment: Because the distribution of $Y/X$ conditional on $X$ does not depend on $X,$ you're done.

Answer (score 6):

*Conditioned* on $X$ having value $x$, the distribution of $Y$ is $N(x,x^2)$. The *conditional* distribution of $Z = \dfrac YX$ given that $X=x$ is the same as the distribution of $\dfrac Yx$ which, as you have discovered, is an $N(1,1)$.  distribution. Thus, $$f_{Z \mid X=x}(\alpha
\mid X=x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\alpha-1)^2}{2}\right)$$ for all choices of $x$ and so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\alpha-1)^2}{2}\right)$ is also the *unconditional* density $f_Z(\alpha)$ of $Z$. Next, note that
\begin{align}f_{Z, X}(\alpha,x)&= f_{Z \mid X=x}(\alpha
\mid X=x)\cdot f_X(x)\\
&=  f_Z(\alpha)\cdot f_X(x) \end{align}
for all choices of $x$ and $\alpha$, that is,  $Z = \dfrac YX$ and $X$ are independent random variables. Note also that the result holds for all choices for the density of $X$; in particular, we did not explicitly use the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed at all.

Answer (score 5):

You have

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) =\frac{v}{\sqrt{2\pi}v^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2v^2}(uv-v)^2}I_{\mathscr Y}((u,v))$$  though I think you should extend the square root to $\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{2\pi v^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2v^2}(uv-v)^2}I_{\mathscr Y}(u,v)$.

There are $v$s you can cancel to give

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}I_{\mathscr Y}(u,v)$$

and since $I_{\mathscr Y}(u,v)$ depends on $v$ but not on $u$, this shows independence by decomposition into the marginal densities $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}$ and  $I_{\mathscr Y}(v)$.